# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined when liking

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, axios

I'm creating a site allowing me to create posts, as well as to comment on them.
I have a problem when I like or dislike a comment.

I get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

I have already implemented the like/dislike feature for posts and have not encountered any problems.

I'm open to any proposal to move forward.

my github project : https://github.com/AlexisAndre34/mernswiftproject

[image]

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## You are trying to map over something that's undefined

check your data exists first

`data && data.length > 0 && data.map(...`

Comment: thank you for your response, 
I've done this and it work as long as I don't like the comment.
When I like I get the post without the comments, as if they didn't have time to load.